# Condition depends on another condition: conditional condition

Tags: javascript

I have implemented a `condition2` depending upon a `condition1` like this:

```
// condition1 comes from elsewhere
let condition2;
if(condition1){
    condition2='task.done'
}else{
    condition2='! task.done'
}
mappedTasks=tasks.map((task,idx)=>{
    if(eval(condition2)){
        return /* stuff */
    }else{
        return /* other stuff */
    }
});
```

However, function `eval` cannot do the job and I receive error like:

> ReferenceError: task is not defined at eval

I wonder if anybody knows what is the best way to implement that conditional condition.

---

Now the code works with:

```
let condition2;
if(condition1){
    condition2=task=>task.done;
}else{
    condition2=task=>!task.done;
}
mappedTasks=tasks.map((task,idx)=>{
    if(condition2(task)){
        return /* stuff */
    }else{
        return /* other stuff */
    }
});
```

Comment: @brso05 because the OP wants to evaluate either `task.done` or `!task.done` in that callback function; `task` is a parameter to the `.map()` callback.

Comment: @Pointy That's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `eval` when you can avoid it (ie never use it).

Here for example you can define the 2nd condition as a function (there are other ways to meet the same result):

```
if (condition1){
    condition2 = function (task) { return task.done; }
} else {
    condition2 = function (task) { return !task.done; }
}
mappedTasks = tasks.map((task,idx)=>{
    if (condition2(task)) {
        return /* stuff */
    } else {
        return /* other stuff */
    }
});
```

Comment: You're correct, but note that the OP could just pass `condition2` directly to `.map()` as the callback. (Maybe; depends on context.)

Comment: @Pointy I was more trying to give a general direction (there are other ways indeed and the one I gave is probably not the best). Thanks for point(y)ing it out :D